# prevent multiple copies within function with static

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, random

I've a function to generate random characters from a set of alphabets. This function would be called multiple times and thus I'm trying to make it use same set of variables, ie have same seed so that strings don't repeat as long as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

std::string generateRandomChar(const unsigned int _len)
    {
        std::string result;
        result.reserve(_len);

        static constexpr char alphanum[] = "0123456789"
                                           "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                           "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 61);

        for (int i = 0; i < _len; 
            result += (alphanum[dis(gen)]);
        }
        return result;
    }

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        std::cout << generateRandomChar(10) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have any expertise with c++11  functions and I was only using `srand` and friends earlier, so I might be making lots of mistakes here. Currently it works and generates tons of strings without repeating, but I'm sure I could make either of -

- `std::random_device rd;`
- `std::mt19937 gen(rd());`
- `std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 61);`

static variable too, so that it isn't calculated each time the function is called because that would be waste right?

So which one should be static here? Are there any mistakes/improvements that you see here?

Thankyou :D

edit - here's an ideone link - http://ideone.com/e7ssXo

Comment: You can move `std::uniform_int_distribution<> ...` out of the loop. No need to construct one everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow unit test, I suggest to move the generator outside of the function, something like

```
std::string generateRandomChar(const unsigned int len, std::mt19937& gen)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(len);

    static constexpr char alphanum[] = "0123456789"
                                       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 61);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        result += (alphanum[dis(gen)]);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << generateRandomChar(10, gen) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

or create a class

```
class RandomCharGenerator
{
public:
    RandomCharGenerator() : RandomCharGenerator(std::random_device{}()) {}

    template <typename T>
    RandomCharGenerator(T&& seed) : gen(std::forward<T>(seed)) {}

    std::string operator() (const unsigned int len)
    {
        std::string result;
        result.reserve(len);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            result += (alphanum[dis(gen)]);
        }
        return result;
    }

private:
    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{0, 61};
    static constexpr char alphanum[] = "0123456789"
                                       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
};

int main() {
    RandomCharGenerator charGenerator{};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << charGenerator(10) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can eventually templated things to allow other rand generator.

Answer (score 2):

> So which one should be static here?

Either `std::mt19937 gen` or none of them.

`std::random_device` generates uniformly-distributed random integers using non-deterministic entropy source, if available. Your code uses `std::random_device` output as a seed for `std::mt19937` pseudo-random generator. So you are very likely to have good, non-deterministic seeds for `std::mt19937` if you run on a PC, and thus there is no need to make any of them static. I suppose that `std::random_device` is implemented as a pure-procedural PRNG only on low-end controllers.

On the other hand, one-time seeding is more idiomatic, so you may declare `std::mt19937` as static. `std::mt19937` itself implements a high-quality PRNG algorithm with 19937 bits of state, so it's period probably exceeds the Universe lifetime (or at least the [stelliferous era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe#Stelliferous_Era)), if the generator is running on a modern PC.

There is no need to make `std::uniform_int_distribution` static, as it's only a wrapper which modifies actual generator's output according to desired distribution properties. So it's up to you to decide whether make it static or not.

Comment: why not to make `std::random_device rd;` static when `std::mt19937 gen` would be static? It instantiates with the previous call itself...

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `random_device` and `mt19937` static. Currently you are constructing one everytime the function is called (IIRC, `mt19937` is expensive to construct. Someone corect me). Also, your `uniform_int_distribution` can be moved out of the loop. This question is better suited for codereview as it already works and you are looking for improvements.

TL;DR: You can make all of them static.